# Optimal ML method to detect coupling in tabulated data

Tags: machine-learning, python

Consider a dataset with these features

- state (s)
- store_id (s_id)
- transaction_id (t_id)
- product_id (p_id)
- unit_price (p_p)

```
(s),(s_id),(t_id),(p_id),(p_p)   
"MN", 111, 222, 987, 1.23   
"MN", 111, 222, 987, 1.23   
"MN", 111, 222, 222, 2.99     
"MN", 123, 333, 987, 1.25     
"MN", 123, 333, 222, 2.99    
"NV", 567, 345, 987, 0.23      
"NV", 567, 345, 987, 0.23    
"NV", 567, 345, 987, 0.23     
"FL", 345, 333, 222, 9.99    
"FL", 345, 333, 222, 9.99
```

(We have some billion rows like this)

We can see that MN tends to buy 987 together with 222, whereas other states buy those separately. We also see that MN customers are very sensitive to price: people buy two items at a price of \$1.23, but only one item at a price of \$1.25.
Both NV and FL tend to buy 987 and 222 separately.

My question is. Which tool is optimal for this analysis? Decision trees? XGBoost? NN?